# Unix: how to delete lines that contain more than N consecutive upper case characters?

Tags: unix, sed

I want to delete lines in a file with 3 or more consecutive upper case characters.

Input:

```
ABBOTT FLORIST MIAMI BEACH
Abbott Lake Loop
Abbott Philip DDS
```

Output:

```
Abbot Lake Loop
```

I tried `sed 's/[A-Z]{3}/g' infile` but does not give me desired results.  Any help?

Answer (score 3):

One way using GNU sed:

```
sed -r '/[A-Z]{3,}/d' file
```

grep can also be used :

```
grep -vE "[A-Z]{3,}" file
```

Comment: I was just about to post a grep example, but you beat me to it by 4 seconds.

Comment: Logically speaking, if you are going to delete a line with three or more somethings, then a condition of three somethings is all that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternate using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/[A-Z]{3,}/{next}1' file
Abbott Lake Loop
```

Comment: If you running `gnu awk` `3.x`, you need the switch `--re-interval` to make this work: `awk --re-interval '/[A-Z]{3,}/{next}1' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/[A-Z]\{3,\}/ p' infile
```

print only line with at least 3 upper letter together

your sed (`sed 's/[A-Z]{3}/g' infile`) is a partial sed action

- create a substitution of something, so print a least an empty line for every line of input
- you select a Upper case char followed by `{3}`litteraly, missing the escape `\` before `{`
- you select a pattern but dont give any substitution result. `s/selectpattern/resultpattern/option`